# Website authentication with Azure AD and Azure AD B2C

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Here's the context :

I have currently a Corporate Azure AD tenant  (Teams, ...) and created a B2C tenant dedicated to my customers which I plan to use for my website authentication.

I guess It is the purpose of the "multi-tenant" option when registering the app but I wonder If I can limit only to the two tenants I own and not opening my website to anyone which has a Microsoft account (for what I understand reading the Microsoft documentation).

If anyone which had already set up a similar authentication process can guide me maybe or just give me some tips to do website authentication by checking if the user account is valid in one of the two tenants ?

Thank you in advance and feel free to ask if you need any more information (maybe I wasn't clear enough).

Answer (score 1):

In Azure AD B2C using custom policies you can [set up sign-in for Multi-tenant Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga) which allows users from multiple Azure AD tenants to sign in, without you having to configure an identity provider for each tenant.

In the custom policy using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` as the value for **ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes** you can restrict access to specific list of Azure AD tenant users who can sign in.

Please refer the above mentioned document on how to sent up the configuration, as you can see in the [add claim provider section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga#add-a-claims-provider) how to configure multiple organizations/Tenants with the comma separator.

```
<Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Item>
```

Please refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started) and [samples](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples) which helps you in getting started with custom policies

Comment: Thank you, is this method still valid when we are talking about a basic Azure AD and an Azure AD B2C ? Or only if we are talking about two B2C tenants ?

Comment: This is valid for the Azure AD B2C with Azure AD as IDP (Azure AD restricted for only Two specified tenants)